# Removing navigation bar line in Xamarin.iOS not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.Forms application and currently working on removing the line under the navigation bar on `iOS`.

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
   public MainPage()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      var homePage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage())
      {
         Title = "Home",
         Icon = "home.png"
      };
      var helpPage = new NavigationPage(new HelpPage())
      {
         Title = "Help",
         Icon = "help.png"
      };
      // other declarations here

      Children.Add(homePage);
      Children.Add(helpPage);
      // and more
   }
}
```

I have tried `UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();` in the `AppDelegate` but it's not working at all so I created the following renderer.

```
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(Japanese.iOS.NavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace Japanese.iOS
{
    public class NavigationPageRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
        }
    }
}
```

This works but only in the `HomePage` which is the first page that would open when the application starts.

[image]
As the image below shows the `HelpPage` still has the line showing as well as the rest of my pages.

[image]
Anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When the page loads does viewdidload method gets called?

Comment: @G.hakim it does 5 times which is also the number of tabs I have

Comment: I am talking about when you navigate to the help page! or is the help page also inside the same tab page?

Comment: ViewDidLoad method is called 5 times all at the same time when I first open the app. Its not being called again when I navigate to different tabs

Comment: Is help also a page in your tabs?

Comment: Instead of using `UINavigationBar.Appearance` , try using `NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();` . That's how we have it coded and it's working well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the Appearance and ShadowImage on the NavigationBar instance in the PageRenderer

```
public class NavigationPageRenderer : NavigationRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
        NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
    }
}
```

Xamarin already provides property to hide the Separator through Platform Sepcifics - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/platform-specifics/consuming/ios#navigationpage-hideseparatorbar

Comment: Thanks. This works but `NavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage` should be `NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage` :-)

Comment: The platform specific does not work. Nor this code. iphone 11 ios 13.